# apiClient.EnvelopeDocumentFields: update returns request 200

Tags: arrays, docusignapi

I am testing code to update custom fields in a DocuSign envelope base off the code listed on their site page. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentFields/update#request
I receive a response code of 200 but none of the changes are reflected in the document.
Does anyone know why this would happen?

{"documentFields": [{"name":"CustomerName", "value":"Test Lab"}]}

Comment: 1. What is the status of the envelope?

Comment: 2. How do you know they were not updated?

Comment: (note custom fields will not be visible in the document, it's just meta-data, if you are trying to update tabs - that's a different thing.

Comment: 1 The envelope status is "sent".  2. The updates were not visible in the copy downloaded after the update script was processed.

Comment: How are tabs updated?

Comment: These are custom fields or tabs? if you want to update tabs, you need to use a different API

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (based on our discussion above) is update tabs not custom fields.
 You need to use the API here (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/update)

```
PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/tabs
```

For your specific envelope and document